# Is that possible to create new email account using EWS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

I'm wondering is that possible to create new eamil account using Exchange Web Service? For example, if I want to register a new account : asdf@mail.local, is that possible to do it using EWS? Thank you.

Comment: With or without adding a user to your active directory?

Comment: What I want to do is create user account by program, not manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EWS is not suited for this task. You would have to automate the Exchange cmdlets (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997663.aspx). This can be done from C# for example.